# How to convert a mutating loop into functional style?

Tags: random, rust

I want to implement an array with 256 random numbers and the numbers must be a value between 0 and 1 inclusively.

This code works, but I would like to make it more functional. How can I convert section 2 into a functional style and chain it with the expression in section 1?

```
let t: f64 = 1.0;
let n = 256;
let dt: f64 = t / n as f64;

let mut numbers = Vec::<f64>::with_capacity(n);
let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();

// section 1
numbers = iter::repeat(())
    .map(|()| rng.gen_range(0., 1.))
    .take(n)
    .collect::<Vec<f64>>();

// section 2  
for i in 0 .. n {
    numbers[i] = numbers[i] * dt.sqrt();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Converting section 2 is just a simple `map`:

```
numbers = numbers.into_iter()
    .map(|x| x * dt.sqrt())
    .collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

To combine, just throw in the `map` at some point:

```
numbers = iter::repeat(())
    .map(|()| rng.gen_range(0., 1.))
    .map(|x| x * dt.sqrt())
    .take(N)
    .collect::<Vec<f64>>();
```

Or if you prefer:

```
numbers = iter::repeat(())
    .map(|()| rng.gen_range(0., 1.) * dt.sqrt())
    .take(N)
    .collect::<Vec<f64>>();
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one solution [playground](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=83352becb8179ae6ef5ad82d861790d9&version=stable&mode=debug)

```
extern crate rand;

use rand::*;

fn main() {
    let t: f64 = 1.0;
    let n = 256;
    let dt = t / f64::from(n);
    let sdt = dt.sqrt();

    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let numbers: Vec<f64> = (0..n).map(|_| rng.gen_range(0., 1.) * sdt).collect();

    println!("{:#?}", numbers);
}
```

Some small changes that were suggested by clippy were made.

Comment: Thanks for your help, much appreciated.